# Electron: Send IPC messages from React to Electron main process?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Say I want to build a simple file explorer Electron app, and design the UI with React. Now, I need React to send the appropriate IPC calls from a Component to the main process of Electron, and receive replies containing filenames for the File explorer that is rendered by React.

How do I go about doing it? There are unfortunately no recent tutorials for this.

Comment: It's documented here. There are also examples https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: and here's a [db example](https://wykrhm.medium.com/creating-standalone-desktop-applications-with-react-electron-and-sqlite3-269dbb310aee) using contextIsolation and IPC

Comment: @Tracer69 I know about using the 'ipcMain' and 'ipcRenderer' modules. My question was, how do I access them from within a React rendered UI.

Comment: Through the ``ipcRenderer`` exported by the ``electron`` package (as stated in the example)

Comment: @pilchard Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, @pilchard's comment pointed me to a blog post titled [Creating standalone Desktop Applications with React, Electron and SQLite3](https://wykrhm.medium.com/creating-standalone-desktop-applications-with-react-electron-and-sqlite3-269dbb310aee), and that finally gave me the best answer.

You use what is called a `contextBridge`, use it to create a api to bridge the renderer process and main process, and expose only the needed functions. Read the post I mentioned above (scroll down to the '**Communication Between React & Electron**' section), and you'll get it.